# Let $F:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous. Suppose $F$ is differentiable on (0,1), $F(0) = 0$ and $F(x)>0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

Let $F:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous. Suppose $F$ is differentiable on (0,1), $F(0) = 0$ and $F(x)>0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Prove that there exists $r,s \in (0,1)$ such that $r + s = 1$ and $8\frac{F'(r)}{F(r)} = 5\frac{F'(s)}{F(s)}$

It seems that this question requires the mean-value theorem. I considered a function G(x) = F(x)F(1-x) and proved the case $\frac{F'(r)}{F(r)} = \frac{F'(s)}{F(s)}$, but for the case involving two different constants. I have no clue. Really thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Rolle's theorem to
$$g(x):=8\ln F(x)+5\ln F(1-x).$$
$\lim_0g=\lim_1g=-\infty$ hence $g'$ must vanish somewhere inbetween.

Comment: Do you mean g'(x) = 0 somewhere in between?

Comment: Oh right I understand the meaning of vanish now. That means that the value of the function is simply 0. Really appreciate your solution!